# LibGdx moveTo action not executed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making an app and i have an annoying bug/error: when i want my image to move gradually upwards, it doesn't do anything. Here is some of my code:

```
public void checkButtons(){
        MoveToAction moveUp = new MoveToAction();
        moveUp.setDuration(actionDuration);
        moveUp.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        MoveToAction moveDown = new MoveToAction();
        moveDown.setDuration(actionDuration);
        moveDown.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 2);

        MoveToAction moveLeft = new MoveToAction();
        moveLeft.setDuration(actionDuration);
        moveLeft.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 2, 0);

        MoveToAction moveRight = new MoveToAction();
        moveRight.setDuration(actionDuration);
        moveRight.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0);
        if (goingUp == true){
            red_dot.addAction(moveUp);
            if (goingUp == false){
                red_dot.removeAction(moveUp);
            }
        }
        if (goingDown == true){
            red_dot.addAction(moveDown);
            if (goingDown == false){
                red_dot.removeAction(moveDown);
            }
        }
        if (goingLeft == true){
            red_dot.addAction(moveLeft);
            if (goingLeft == false){
                red_dot.removeAction(moveLeft);
            }
        }
        if (goingRight == true){
            red_dot.addAction(moveRight);
            if (goingRight == false){
                red_dot.removeAction(moveRight);
            }
        }
```

red_dot is an image and the rest of the variables are pretty straightforward.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- Are you calling `stage.act()`?
- Is your `actionDuration` non-zero?
- Are you sure about those coordinates? Most of them look like they would be off-screen if you're using a ScreenViewport. And if you're not, why would the size of the screen have anything to do with where you want to move your object?

It also seems you have some kind of misunderstanding about logic flow. The code structure that you repeat four times doesn't make sense:

```
if (someCriterion == true) {;
    doSomething();
    if (someCriterion == false) {
        //Code in here will never be called unless `doSomething()` immediately causes
        //someCriterion to become false as a side effect (which addAction() will not do).
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you are thinking either that the code under `addAction` will get called after the action is complete, or that it will be called repeatedly. But neither is the case. If you want to stop the actions early, you must remove them at the spot in your code where you are changing variables such as `goingUp` to false.

But if you are just trying to remove actions that are complete, that is unnecessary, because that happens automatically.

Also, you shouldn't be creating all those extra actions that you may not be using. You're generating lots of garbage that could cause stuttering. Only create actions that you are definitely going to use. And instead of using `new MoveToAction()`, use `Actions.moveTo()` to get the action you need from the pool. Then it will not trigger garbage collection when it is complete, because Stage knows to send pooled actions back to the pool for recycling.

Comment: When i call this method from an other class and i call stage.act() there, is that good?

Comment: As long as this actor is in the stage and stage.act is called every frame, that's correct.

Comment: When i call Gdx.graphics.getHeight does it returns a float value?